# The purchase window is no longer prompted

Tags: android-billing, play-billing-library

[image]

I renewed

was

gradle plugin 4.0.1

gradle version 6.1.1

became

gradle plugin 7.1.1

gradle version 7.2

and the shopping window no longer shows .If return back will work.

What can be wrong?

(The most interesting thing is that if you compile via USB debugging, it does not work, but if APK then it will work)
Purchases version 5.1.0

[image]

I set the debugging value to false and everything worked (who knows what the reason is)
[image]